# List Targets from Xcode via command line

Tags: xcode, macos

Is it possible to get the targets of a Xcode project from the command line, or any other way without opening the file in Xcode itself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try

```
xcodebuild -list 


macaroni:CLIClone todd$ xcodebuild -list
Information about project "CLIClone":

Targets:
    CLIClone

Build Configurations:
    Debug
    Release

If no build configuration is specified and -scheme is not passed then "Release" is used.

Schemes:
    CLIClone
```

Comment: That's good. Is there a way to parse them into a JSON using shell?

Comment: Using `xcodebuild -list -json` returns the same result in JSON. You can then use "jq" or other tools to manipulate the JSON data.